window.onload event does not seem to be working
Here is my code for onload event:
let statElements = []; 
let data = [];
const dailyBtn = document.getElementById("daily");
const weeklyBtn = document.getElementById("weekly");
const monthlyBtn = document.getElementById("monthly");
async function fetchDataAndProcess() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("data.json");
        data = await response.json();

        const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section.card");

        sections.forEach((section, index) => {
            const title = data[index].title.toLowerCase();
            const h2Element = section.querySelector(`h2.${title}-stats`);
            const pElement = section.querySelector(`p.${title}-stats`);

            statElements.push({
                h2: h2Element,
                p: pElement
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching or processing data:", error);
    }
}
fetchDataAndProcess();
function weekly() {
    statElements.forEach((element, index) => {
        element.h2.textContent = `${data[index].timeframes.weekly.current}hrs`;
        element.p.textContent = `Last Week - ${data[index].timeframes.weekly.previous}hrs`;
    });
    weeklyBtn.style.color = "white";
    monthlyBtn.style.color = "hsl(235, 45%, 61%)";
    dailyBtn.style.color = "hsl(235, 45%, 61%)";
}
window.onload =  weekly;

Basically what this is supposed to do is retrieve h2 and p elements from each section and set their textcontent to the data in the json object. The problem I am having is sometimes, it is working, sometimes, it seems not to have been executed because I don't see the contents of my h2 and p have been filled. So, I am wondering if it is because of using async function or using onload event. Maybe i should use something else?
I changed the window event to DOMContentLoaded, nothing changed. I changed the window event by adding event listener load, still the problem did not disappear.

Add some console.log("start of fetch") console.log(fetch data") console.log("start of weekly") and look at what order they appear.

IOW, fetchDataAndProcess() hasn't finished before weekly() is attempting to run.

Suggestion: change to window.onload = fetchDataAndProcess() then call weekly() after the data has loaded.

@fdomn-m - though, that would delay processing compared to current (attempted) code - though, looking at it again, the fetchDataAndProcess kind of depends on the DOM being loaded :p

@JaromandaX good catch that it would delay the fetch.   One reason to use jquery's doc.ready as it fires immediately if doc is already ready.  So best approach would likely be: start the fetch immediately, when data is received then check if DOM loaded - if not loaded, add DOMContentLoaded event to process data otherwise process data immediately.  Where "process data" is both the second half of fetchDataAndProcess and weekly.

Since fetchDataAndProcess() is async, you'd want to wait for it to finish.
Move the call to it underneath the function weekly() invocation, then chain them with e.g. .then() (unless top-level await is available):
fetchDataAndProcess().then(weekly);

